# Display Text From ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, jtextfield

I'm trying to display data that I have stored in an ArrayList into JtextField. for example I would like to get the (ID,Name,Age,Gender) at point 0 in the array and display them into JtextFields.

I have tried the code below but it does not work as expected:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GPSDataEnter.size(); i++) {
    LatTextData.append((String) GPSDataEnter.get(i));
}
```

Comment: @assylias I've tried for (int i = 0; i < GPSDataEnter.size(); i++) {
    LatTextData.append((String) GPSDataEnter.get(i));
   }

Comment: and few others put nothing I've tried so far worked.

Comment: Does get(i) return a string or a user defined type? And by not working as expected, care to clarify?

Comment: it will be returning a string.

Comment: So.. what do you mean by not working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string ArrayData = string.Empty;
    ArrayList listData = new ArrayList();
        foreach (string textItem in listData)

        {

        ArrayData = ArrayData + ", " + textItem;

        }

   textBox1.setText(ArrayData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .setText() method of the JTextField. Here is the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html

A short example:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

... Fill up the list somehow ...


JTextField myField = new JTextField();
myField.setText(myList.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyArrayList.size(); i++) {
    MyJTextField.setText(MyJTextField.getText() + MyArrayList.get(i) + "\n");
}
```

Your probem was rewriting!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your ArrayList is

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
```

Then,

```
JTextField.setText(arrayList[i]); //index of arrayList;
```